# Convert Unicode to double ASCII letters in Python (ß -> ss)

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

Some Unicode characters can also be written as two ASCII letters (e.g.: ß -> ss, å -> aa). Is there any way to convert these in Python, without having a list with all of them?

#### LATER EDIT:

This kind of conversion is done by a lof of websites, including Stackoverflow (url from this page was converted), and Twitter. I'm curious how they do it.

Comment: Since the rules for these conversions differ depending on the culture and context (ß -> ss isn't always legit, sometimes ß -> sz is the better fit), it would likely not be a default module.

Comment: å -> aa may or may not be a valid transformation, depending on locale

Comment: @STATUS As Austrian myself I can't think of a single word where I'd use sz instead of ss as replacement for ß. I assume the "new" spelling reforms may have something to do with that, I do see that quite often in older books. Or I'm just missing all examples right now ;)

Comment: @Voo: I think you are missing words where it becomes - simply put - very ambiguous if you do ß -> ss. Example: Maße -> Masse. Writing it as Masze would make it obvious what's meant, even though it looks "odd" :) ... and if you don't have a context (i.e. the word appears alone in a table heading instead of a sentence, this will lead to confusion). Similar reasoning can be applied to some all-uppercase words.

Comment: @STATUS Ok yeah "Nur in Maße" vs. "Nur in Masse" could lend itself to confusion. We could probably solve that with a dictionary, but it's probably rare enough to work good enough in practice.

Comment: @Voo: agreed. But to give you another example: some cultures that have ö will convert that to oe, others simply to o. Now machines aren't very good at this kind of guess work. So you can get close depending on the culture (especially if you know it), but there is no generic solution to the problem.

Comment: ß → sz would be unusual in any language I know (I'm German and I know it's allowed there for uppercase words but only if confusion arises. You never see it in the wild, though).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no universal rules.

You could try [unidecode](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) module to transliterate Unicode text to ASCII.